# multiple dex files define produce com.android.dex.DexException

Tags: android, android-studio, dex

Background:  Laptop 1 had 64bit Windows 7, Android Studio 2.2.3, AWS SDK 2.3.9.  I switched to laptop two, a new install of 64bit Windows 7, reinstalled Android Studio 2.2.3, AWS SDK 2.3.9, and attempted to re-compile the code and run it on a Nexus 5 emulated device.

I get this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/cognito/CognitoSyncManager$1;

These are things I have done:

I have googled and dug through the details of dozens of posts that had the "...Multiple dex files define..." error including all the stackoverflow recommendations.

I have turned on --stacktrace and --debug and --info to get more detailed error messaging/detail.

I have searched around and played with dozens of settings that have to do with path settings for the environment and the project and the Make process.

I have searched my harddrive for any files that could contain the CognitoSyncManager (from the AWS SDK).  In the libs directory.  In .gradle directories.  In the cache and appdata directories.  Dozens of places.

I ran the dependencies analysis tool from Studio thinking that a name change in the app might have split some kind of dependency tree.

My guess (if I still have one after all of that) is that I have to take the message literally and the studio really is finding two files with conflicting definition of the class but I just can't find the settings to redirect the Make process elsewhere.

I am so new to android development.  The app itself only has a few lines of code in the manifest, in one layout file, one java file, a few modifications to some gradle scripts.  You have to assume I am missing something really basic:(

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Can you temporary comment out the AWS SDK dependency and try to rebuild? Does it compile?

Comment: update:  I know this may not be satisfactory to anyone least of all me, but this is what I did.  I started a brand new empty project and added every change in environment, every configuration, every block of code back in piece by piece until I could exactly isolate where every single error was coming from.  I was able to reproduce this particular error a few times at the beginning but as I isolated each section of functionality with builds between each tiny change this one went away, was replaced by others, and never came back...